# Angular Directives Tests fail after wrapping in an IIFE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After reading John Papa's AngularJS [style guide on IIFEs](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#iife), I began to wrap all my files in IIFEs. I ran into a problem when I wrap my menubar directive file in an IIFE. The tests fail claiming my menubar directive's controller is undefined.

> ReferenceError: MenubarController is not defined
>           at Object. (/Users/eso/dev/Prismo/frontend/prismo-frontend/app/menubar/directives_test.js:9:2473)
>           at Object.invoke (/Users/eso/dev/Prismo/frontend/prismo-frontend/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9:139719)
>           at Object.workFn (/Users/eso/dev/Prismo/frontend/prismo-frontend/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:9:69713)
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadCurrentUser' of undefined
>           at Object. (/Users/eso/dev/Prismo/frontend/prismo-frontend/app/menubar/directives_test.js:9:3634)
>       Error: Unflushed requests: 1
>           at Function.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest (/Users/eso/dev/Prismo/frontend/prismo-frontend/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:9:45282)
>           at Object. (/Users/eso/dev/Prismo/frontend/prismo-frontend/app/menubar/directives_test.js:9:2853)

My code is too long to post here; I've provided a link to the github repo commit:

[Menubar directives.js file](https://github.com/ericso/prismo-frontend/blob/1f94d6ca456b66fcaa86c41d6b313176d87797cd/app/menubar/directives.js)

The tests pass before the IIFE, but fail after adding the IIFE. The other tests, however, pass; all the other controllers, services, etc, even after adding the IIFEs. Any thoughts?

Edit: Note that building the app and deploying it results in a working app with no errors. The menubar directive renders and works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the directive is wrapped on iife you have no access to the `MenubarController` object [on the test](https://github.com/ericso/prismo-frontend/blob/1f94d6ca456b66fcaa86c41d6b313176d87797cd/app/menubar/directives_test.js#L63). Use a string instead:

```
ctrl = controller('MenubarController', deps, data);
```

On the directive file you must register the controller in your angular module with the same name and add it to the directive by string too:

```
.directive('menubar', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'menubar/menubar.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        appname: '=',
        tabs: '='
      },
      controller: 'MenubarController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
  })
  .controller('MenubarController', MenubarController)
```

Comment: So this worked, but it feels like it violates some sort of rule about hiding what's supposed to be a private controller for a directive.

Comment: Reflecting back on this now, it's kind of a "DUH" moment. The whole point of wrapping in an IIFE is to remove objects from the global scope, which, was how I was passing the controller to the test.